# adding HTML form input to database

Tags: php, mysql

Kindly need assistance in my coding, I have a database named Books with table called OpenBooks I would like to add the html form which are user inputs into the table and echo confirmation.

```
<?php

    $Title = $_POST['Title'];
    $Author = $_POST['Author'];
    $Series = $_POST['Series'];
    $Price =$_POST['price'];

    //database connection

   $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','books');
   if(!$connection){
      die("Database connection failed");
   }
   $query = "INSERT INTO OpenBooks(Title,Author,series,price)";
   $query .= " VALUES ('$Title', '$Author', '$series', '$price')";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

}
?>
```

Comment: You set $Series and $Price but try to enter $series and $price. If it still doesnt work then tell us what result or errors are you getting and try echoing the for variables to check they exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    echo 'yay, done';
}
```

And you need `$Price` instead of `price` and rest of variables starting from capital letter.